Google Sheet - Image as button
I would like to use an image as a button for me to go to another cell in the same sheet. Happy if I can get someone to share the appropriate scripts. Thanks
I have tried a button to go to another sheet in the same document and it ran properly. However, I never try to provide a button which can go to another cell in the same sheet

why did you add the javascript-objects tag, do you want a javascript code to do what you want? or just to do it in the Google Sheet?

Maybe this will help: https://golayer.io/blog/google-sheets/google-sheets-button/
